# Excepciones en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código el cuál deberá devolver una lista de números enteros; está lista tendrá el tamaño especificado en el parámetro pasado

En caso de que el parámetro que se le pase no sea de tipo int, la función lanzará una excepción TypeError con el mensaje

> "Se ha producido un TypeError"

En el caso de que el parámetro que se le pase sea de tipo int, pero no 
positivo, la función lanzará la excepción ValueError con el mensaje "Se ha producido un ValueError"

Si el parámetro que se le pasa tiene es del tipo y valor correcto, la función pedirá al usuario la entrada de tantos números como indica el valor del parámetro y formará con ellos una lista, añadiendo los elementos segun el orden que los lea. En caso de que el usuario se equivoque al introducir los valores, la función tratará la excepción que se produzca y continuará pidiendo números al usuario hasta que tenga todos los que necesita

```
def tratamiento_excepciones(number):
    while number == True:
        if number == int and number < 0:
            entrada_datos = int(input("Introduzca un número: "))
            new_list = []
            new_list.append(entrada_datos)
            return new_list
        elif type(number) != int:
            raise TypeError("Se ha producido un TypeError")
        elif number < 0:
            raise ValueError("Se ha producido un ValueError")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(tratamiento_excepciones(5))
```

La duda es que me devuelve continuamente None, he probado con este fragmento y con otro que he contruido que puedo adjuntar pero no añade los elementos en la lista correspondiente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

- El ciclo `while` no tiene sentido tal como lo usas. Dentro del ciclo solo debe pedirse enteros al usuario y agregarlos a la lista, no validar el argumento `number`. Además, debes decrementar `number` en cada iteración o de lo contrario tendrás un ciclo infinito. La lista debes definirla fuera del ciclo o de lo contrario solo contendrá el último elemento ingresado.
- La comprobación `number == int` nunca va a ser cierta, **comparas una instancia de `int` con la clase/tipo `int`**. Siempre van a ser objetos distintos. Debes usar `isinstance()`. Esto hace que la función  retorne `None` (retorno por defecto de cualquier función) o lance una excepción.
- El `return` debe producirse al final de todo, fuera del ciclo `while`, cuando la lista esté completa.

El código podría quedar algo así:

```
def tratamiento_excepciones(number):
    if not isinstance(number, int):
        raise TypeError("Se ha producido un TypeError")
    elif number < 0:
        raise ValueError("Se ha producido un ValueError")

    new_list = []
    while number:
        try:
            entrada_datos = int(input("Introduzca un número: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("No ha ingresado un entero. Inténtelo de nuevo.")
        else:
            new_list.append(entrada_datos)
            number -= 1
    return new_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(tratamiento_excepciones(5))
```

Comment: Puedes usar `type(number) == int`, la diferencia principal es que no soporta herencia, el argumento debe ser siempre un objeto de `int`, no soportando posibles subclases de la misma. En cuanto al uso de `raise`, ¿te refieres a usarlo en el bloque `try-except-else` que valida las entradas del usuario o es otra cosa?

Comment: El uso del try-except es solo por si el usuario ingresa algo que no sea un entero para ingresar en la lista. ¿Si esto ocurre que debería pasar? Si al pedir los números al usuario  por ejemplo en vez de ingresar `7` ingresa `hola` que debería ocurrir.? Puedes cambiar el `print` por `continue` o `pass`, en cuyo caso simplemente ignora esa entrada inválida.

Answer (score 0):

HOla Amigo es que estas preguntando

```
number == True:
```

Y number es igual al numero que has ingresado. No es igual a "True" a no ser que escribas "True". Igualmente te sugiero que revises el codigo y si es lo que estas buscando.

Saludos.

Comment: en tu caso ingresas el 5. tratamiento_excepciones(5)